# What is meant by "roots in $Lie(N)$" in root space decomposition of Lie algebras?

Tags: lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, automorphic-forms, definitions, eisenstein-series

Let $G = GL_n$ and $T$ the invertible diagonal matrices and $N$ the upper triangular matrices with only $1$'s on the diagonal. Then the Lie algebra $\mathcal{G}$ has the roots space decomposition 
$$
\mathcal{G} = Lie(T) \oplus \oplus_{\alpha \in \Phi(G,T)} \mathcal{G}_{\alpha}
$$ 
where 
$$
\mathcal{G}_{\alpha} = \{ v \in \mathcal{G} :  Ad(t) v = \alpha(t) v \ (\forall t \in T)   \}. 
$$
So $\Phi(G,T)$ is a subset of $X^*(T)$ and the $\alpha$'s in $\Phi(G,T)$ are called roots. Now what is meant when one says "the roots in $\mathcal{N} = Lie(N)$"? 
Any clarifications would be appreciated. Thank you.

PS. This appears when one is defining $\rho_P$ which appears in the definition of Eisenstein series, and I could not find explanation..

Comment: Roots $\alpha$ such that $\mathcal{G}_\alpha$ is subset of $\mathcal{N}$. Next time please ask basic terminology questions on math.stackexchange.

Comment: Many of the details that arise in talking about automorphic forms and Eisenstein series are much more elementary than the issues at hand, so will not be explained. In particular, often, _not_ finding an explanation or reference in the text is a strong clue that the thing is much more elementary.

Comment: @VítTuček, as pointed out at https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4217/are-we-making-it-too-tempting-easy-to-send-inappropriate-posts-to-mse , we shouldn't just migrate all too-elementary questions to MSE.  In this case, I think that the answer is not to ask on any SE site, but to consult a reference on algebraic groups, or to ask an advisor or classmate.

Comment: @LSpice Thanks. Noted.

Comment: @paulgarrett: This is always a difficulty for grad students getting in the field. It can be hard to tell, without much expertise to begin with, whether a question is non-trivial or not, or what the missing information is. I was recently looking at Arthur's first paper and even that poses major difficulties for someone not fluent with Harish-Chandra's work... If only there were an "Automorphic forms and Eisenstein series for dummies..." or "Harish-Chandra for dummies/grad students..."